# Fluid Design on Mobile Device

Tags: css, mobile, fluid-layout

I am attempting to code a "semi-fluid" item for a mobile site and need a bit of help.

What I am looking to do is realign the layout when viewed vertical or horizontal.

When viewed vertically it should be...

[image]

Horizontal should be...

[image]

Comment: you may need to give a better description, have you got any css/html you've tried already?

The more you give the better the responses will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is a fairly rudimentary example, You can simply float the elements left when the screen is above a certain size. This is accomplished using a media query. You can assign media queries in CSS3 and can find the documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #green, #red {
        float: none;    
    }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brxHf/2/) for the simple solution.